# How can I rewrite the following MS Word VBA macro to be compatible with Word 2007/2010/2013

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I am looking to make my MS Word VBA macro compatible with Word 2007,2010, and 2013 without having to download the MS Office Object Libraries 12,14, and 15 on all my machines. Any types how I can accomplish this? My code is the following and seems to require Object Library 12 & 14 or 15. It doesn't work with just 12,14 or 15.

```
data1 = InputBox("What was the Moving Water damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")
' Validiate data

Do
If data1 > 1 Or data1 < 0 Then
data1 = InputBox("Invalid input. What was the Moving Water damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")
End If
Loop Until (data1 <= 1 And data1 >= 0)

data2 = InputBox("What was the Settlement damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")

Do
If data2 > 1 Or data2 < 0 Then
data2 = InputBox("Invalid input. What was the Settlement damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")
End If
Loop Until (data2 <= 1 And data2 >= 0)

data3 = InputBox("What was the Pre-Exisiting damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")

Do
If data3 > 1 Or data3 < 0 Then
data3 = InputBox("Invalid input. What was the Pre-Exisiting damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")
End If
Loop Until (data3 <= 1 And data3 >= 0)

Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
i = i + 1

' Create table
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=2
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 2).Split NumColumns:=3
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Location:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Quantity (Measurable Area):"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Description:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Analysis:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "Cause(s) of Damage:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = "Recommended Repairs:"

With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With

Dim small As Boolean
small = False
Dim twoSeries As Boolean
twoSeries = False
Dim pieChart As Boolean
pieChart = True

Dim salesChart As Chart
Dim chartWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet


With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With

With ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(4, 2).Range
ActiveDocument.Range(.Start, .Start).Select
End With

' Add in a new chart
Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chartWorkSheet = salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)

' Resize the chart area
chartWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize chartWorkSheet.Range("A1:B4")

' Rename Series 1 as Sales
chartWorkSheet.Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Series 1]]").FormulaR1C1 = "Damage"

' Add data to the chart
chartWorkSheet.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Moving Water"
chartWorkSheet.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "Settlement"
chartWorkSheet.Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "Pre-Exisiting"
chartWorkSheet.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = data1
chartWorkSheet.Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = data2
chartWorkSheet.Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = data3


' Quit Excel, since we no longer need it
salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit

' Put a box around the legend
salesChart.Legend.Format.Line.Visible = msoCTrue

' Fill the background with theme color accent 1
With salesChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill
.Visible = msoTrue
.Solid
.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = wdThemeColorAccent1
End With

' Add a title and format it
salesChart.HasTitle = True
With salesChart.ChartTitle
.Characters.Font.Italic = True
.Characters.Font.Size = 18
.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 100)
.Text = "Damage"
End With


If small Then
' Size and move the chart
 With salesChart.Parent
.Left = 100
.Width = 300
.Height = 150
End With
End If

If pieChart Then
' Set chart type
salesChart.ChartType = xl3DPie
End If

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Endofdoc").Select
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

Comment: are you setting any reference to MS Word from other application? which one application? and please show the code you set that references... what kind of problems you have that you expect you need to download `Office Object Libraries 12,14, and 15`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the code running in Office 2010 and it only references the version 14 libraries. It appears the code has been around for a while, and older references can be removed.

To have it work across different versions, you'd have to change the references from early binding to late binding. That way, you don't need to add the references from the VB Editor for each new version.

Can I use this code sample as an example of Word macros for my students?

Also, if you need help with the late binding (this is an old question) let me know.

Reference for Early Binding: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/interdev/earlyvslatebinding.htm